# How can I use multi-threading with SCS

Tags: multithreading, cvxpy

I installed CVXPY and SCS came with it. I ran several large models with SCS but it uses only 1 core. My models include exponential cones. I am running CVXPY on a linux server with 256 GB memory and 64 cores.

Answer (score 0):

From the options that [cvxpy supports for solvers](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#solve-method-options) there appears to be no multi-threading option for SCS though one is listed for CBC.

But when I run SCS with `acceleration_lookback = 10` (default) I do have 8 of my 16 cores at 100%. Running with `acceleration_lookback = 1` I only see 1 core active.